# How to Convert CAShapeLayer to CAGradientLayer?

Tags: ios, cashapelayer, cagradientlayer

my code of making CAShapeLayer is

```
UIBezierPath *circle = [UIBezierPath bezierPathWithArcCenter:CGPointMake(75, 125)
                                                          radius:50
                                                      startAngle:0
                                                        endAngle:1.8 * M_PI
                                                       clockwise:YES];

    CAShapeLayer *circleLayer = [CAShapeLayer layer];
    [circleLayer setFrame:CGRectMake(200 - 50, 300 - 50, 100, 100)];
    circleLayer.path   = circle.CGPath;
    circleLayer.bounds = CGPathGetBoundingBox(circle.CGPath);
    circleLayer.strokeColor = [UIColor colorWithRed:0.4 green:1.0 blue:0.2 alpha:0.5].CGColor;
    [circleLayer setFillColor:[UIColor clearColor].CGColor];
    circleLayer.lineWidth   = 3.0;

    if ([circleLayer animationForKey:@"SpinAnimation"] == nil) {
        CABasicAnimation* animation = [CABasicAnimation animationWithKeyPath:@"transform.rotation"];
        animation.fromValue = [NSNumber numberWithFloat:0.0f];
        animation.toValue = [NSNumber numberWithFloat: 2 * M_PI];
        animation.duration = 2.0f;
        animation.repeatCount = INFINITY;
        animation.removedOnCompletion = NO;
        [circleLayer addAnimation:animation forKey:@"SpinAnimation"];
    }
    [self.view.layer addSublayer:circleLayer];
```

I want to make CAGradientLayer instead of CAShapeLayer.

REASON: I need to use gradient color in layer, which is not possible in CAShapeLayer.

I want to use yellow to black gradient upon Cirle.

Image :

[image]

In my required output, color is fetched from background image, and put some black at the end, or opacity 0 within layer.

Any Idea, suggestion.

Thanks.

Comment: Is the background color of the view fixed? I mean, the background color is some color you already know (say white).

Comment: Yes, background color of View is fixed @ChengYuHsu

Answer (score 4, accepted):

One quick and dirty trick is adding a gradient layer as a sublayer then put some more layers with the background colors same as the superview (in the original question, it's white).

For example:

1. Add a gradient layer (and set proper `cornerRadius`).

[image: filled gradient layer]

2. Add a smaller layer with white background color at the center of the gradient layer (this will create a *ring*).

[image: ring]

3. Create a small segment of arc with white background color.

[image: ring with gap]

However, this may not be suitable views with background images.
To solve this, you can create a custom subclass of `UIView` and override the `drawRect` method.

Suppose there are instance variables: `startColor`, `endColor`, `radius`, `strokeWidth`, and `mirrored`.

The variable `mirrored` is used to control the position of the gap (cut off left side or right side) and the rotation direction of the animation (clockwise or counter-clockwise).

```
- (void)drawRect:(CGRect)rect
{
    CGContextRef ctx = UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext();

    CGContextSetBlendMode(ctx, kCGBlendModeNormal);

    CGFloat gradientColors[4 * 2];

    extractColorComponents(_startColor, gradientColors, 0);
    extractColorComponents(_endColor, gradientColors, 4);


    CGColorSpaceRef baseSpace = CGColorSpaceCreateDeviceRGB();
    CGGradientRef gradient = CGGradientCreateWithColorComponents(baseSpace, gradientColors, NULL, 2);
    CGColorSpaceRelease(baseSpace);
    baseSpace = nil;

    CGPoint startPoint = CGPointMake(CGRectGetMidX(rect), CGRectGetMinY(rect));
    CGPoint endPoint = CGPointMake(CGRectGetMidX(rect), CGRectGetMaxY(rect));
    CGContextDrawLinearGradient(ctx, gradient, startPoint, endPoint, 0);
    CGGradientRelease(gradient);
    gradient = nil;

    // fill 'clear' color
    CGContextSetFillColorWithColor(ctx, [UIColor clearColor].CGColor);
    CGContextSetStrokeColorWithColor(ctx, [UIColor clearColor].CGColor);

    CGContextSetBlendMode(ctx, kCGBlendModeClear);

    CGFloat innerCircleRadius = _radius - _strokeWidth;

    // fill an 'empty' hole inside the gradient part
    CGContextFillEllipseInRect(ctx, (CGRect){
        {_strokeWidth, _strokeWidth},
        {innerCircleRadius * 2, innerCircleRadius * 2}
    });


    // fill an 'empty' segment of arc
    CGFloat startAngle = _mirrored ? (0.9 * M_PI) : (-0.1 * M_PI);
    CGFloat endAngle = startAngle + 0.2 * M_PI;
    UIBezierPath *path = [UIBezierPath bezierPathWithArcCenter:(CGPoint){_radius, _radius}
                                                        radius:_radius - _strokeWidth * 0.5
                                                    startAngle:startAngle
                                                      endAngle:endAngle
                                                     clockwise:YES];
    path.lineWidth = _strokeWidth;
    CGContextAddPath(ctx, path.CGPath);
    CGContextSetLineWidth(ctx, _strokeWidth + 2);
    CGContextStrokePath(ctx);

    CGContextSetBlendMode(ctx, kCGBlendModeNormal);
}
```

Here's the [complete implementation](https://gist.github.com/cyhsutw/515a96834023802df030) of the view.

Final result:

[image: animated spinner]

**Two rings:**

You can add two rings in your `viewDidLoad` or somewhere else with the following code to achieve the desired effect:

```
- (void)viewDidLoad 
{
    [super viewDidLoad];

    UIColor *startColor = [UIColor colorWithHue:0.02 saturation:0.74 brightness:0.91 alpha:1];
    UIColor *endColor = [UIColor colorWithHue:0.57 saturation:0.76 brightness:0.86 alpha:1];

    CGPoint center = CGPointMake(160, 200);

    Spinner *outerSpinner = [[Spinner alloc] initWithCenter:center
                                                     radius:50
                                                strokeWidth:3
                                                 startColor:startColor
                                                   endColor:endColor
                                                   mirrored:NO];

    Spinner *innerSpinner = [[Spinner alloc] initWithCenter:center
                                                     radius:40
                                                strokeWidth:3
                                                 startColor:startColor
                                                   endColor:endColor
                                                   mirrored:YES];


    [self.view addSubview:outerSpinner];
    [self.view addSubview:innerSpinner];

    [outerSpinner startAnimating];
    [innerSpinner startAnimating];

}
```

Result:

[image: double animated rings]

Comment: Dear, I have achieved it. I have another problem now. I can't make two. :) If you see my image, there are two round, one is clockwise, otherone is anticlockwise :)

Comment: If you could help me in making two, one is clockwise, other one anti-clockwise. As we have complete circle, we can see its stroke, so how we can achieve it with two circles?

Comment: You may create 2 instances of  `Spinner` view with different radii and add proper animations to each views.

Comment: But dear, it will overlap colors :) As both are at same position, one circle is smaller than other

Comment: Can't add two Circles. Giving EXC_BAD_ACCESS.


Spinner *spinner = [[Spinner alloc] initWithCenter:CGPointMake(75, 125) radius:50 strokeWidth:3 startColor:[UIColor yellowColor] endColor:[UIColor blackColor]];

    Spinner *spinner2 = [[Spinner alloc] initWithCenter:CGPointMake(75, 125) radius:40 strokeWidth:3 startColor:[UIColor yellowColor] endColor:[UIColor blackColor]];

    
    [self.view addSubview:spinner];
    [self.view addSubview:spinner2];

Comment: I commented this line     //CGColorRelease(colorRef);

Comment: You're right, that line should be commented out or the color will be released and can't be used again.

Comment: @SamShaikh I've updated my answer, please check it out.

Comment: I also recommend you to check release line, CGColorRelease. It was having problem. I commented it yesterday.

Answer (score -1):

The mask property on CALayer uses the alpha component of the mask layer to determine what should be visible and not. Since both of your colors (black and white) are fully opaque (no transparency) the mask has no effect. To fix this you should change one of the colors to a clear color:

```
gradient.colors = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:(id)[[UIColor blackColor] CGColor], 
                                            (id)[[UIColor clearColor] CGColor], nil];
```

**EDIT**

```
class Colors {
let colorTop = UIColor(red: 192.0/255.0, green: 38.0/255.0, blue: 42.0/255.0, alpha: 1.0).CGColor
let colorBottom = UIColor(red: 35.0/255.0, green: 2.0/255.0, blue: 2.0/255.0, alpha: 1.0).CGColor

let gl: CAGradientLayer

init() {
    gl = CAGradientLayer()
    gl.colors = [ colorTop, colorBottom]
    gl.locations = [ 0.0, 1.0]
}
}
```

Comment: Oh great, but can you explain what is gradient here in your code!

Comment: So, can you find any single object having CAGradientLayer? I think you are not getting my question. Simple I need to change color of stroke color of CAShapeLayer, or use CAGradientLayer from start.